# Comparing between frappe-ui and frappe-react-sdk

Tags: frappe

I am newbie frappe-ui. I see frappe-ui have a lot of component for build application but document about frappe-ui isn't enough. So why we don't use frappe-react-sdk while it has richer component and more enough document than frappe-ui?

I don't choose frappe-ui or frappe-react-sdk to develop application.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not about why we don’t use frappe-react-sdk anyone can use it. But the frappe community seems to not like react a lot, that’s why they don’t use it in there main bench application. Also I have been using both for a while and frappe-react-sdk doesn’t have more UI it’s just that the nature of react itself makes it easier to use those UI.